# How to fix validator "Trailing slash on void elements" info messages on Wordpress site?

Tags: html, wordpress, validation

I've checked my website with HTML validator. And on my site there are informational messages like this: **trailing slash on void elements has no effect and interacts badly with unquoted attribute values**.

[image]

I understand what the problem is. I just need to replace " **/>**" with "**>**" I need to fix them, but the fact is that the site uses various plugins that make editing more difficult.

How i have few ideas how to fix this:

- Find needed line and fix problem in every theme/plugin/wp core file. But it's not right way because after update all changes are dissapear.
- Use something like built-in wordpress filter or hook to use regex or str_replace to replace needed parts of html code.

Perhaps someone has come across a similar situation and will tell you in which direction to look?

Comment: "I need to fix them" — You don't. They're just warnings. The attribute value generated by the plug-in is clearly quoted.